# Handling data from multiple dictionaries in a single variable

Tags: python

Beginner question but I wanted to handle data from multiple dictionaries in a single variable. For example:

```
x = {"age":"24","name":"Bob"}, {"age":"21","name":"George"}
```

In this case, how would I find out what "age" is in each dictionary in x, and put them in a list?
This should be the desired outcome:

```
ages = ["24","21"]
```

This is what I've tried so far but raises an error:

```
x = {"age":24,"name":"Bob"}, {"age":21,"name":"George"}
ages = []
for y in x:
     ages.append(x["age"])
```

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: What error does it raise?

Comment: "x" is a tuple of dictionaries. What is then "y" in your code?

Comment: Just need to append `y['age']` instead of `x['age']`

Comment: `ages=[d['age'] for d in x]`

Answer (score 0):

Use `ages.append(y["age"])` - note the **y** which references each dictionary in the tuple of dictionaries referenced by `x`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you try and find the key of a tuple? You need to use `y`.

```
ages = []
for y in x:
     ages.append(y["age"])
print(ages)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just check whether the dictionary contains the key you want.

```py
if "age" in y:
    ages.append(y["age"])
```